# Type '() => Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type '(file: UploadFile<any>) => boolean | void | Promise<boolean | void>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a project, and this project contains several interfaces, and among these interfaces, I have an interface for uploading an image.

After uploading the image, it is possible for the user to delete it, and a form appears to confirm the deletion process.

But I didn't know how to write the delete function, and for this reason I got this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: UploadProps<any> & { children?: ReactNode; } & RefAttributes<any>): ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>', gave the following error.
```

and this error:

```
Type '() => Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type '(file: UploadFile<any>) => boolean | void | Promise<boolean | void>'
```

How can i solve the problem?

```
import '../../../styles/input/index.scss';
import '../../../styles/dropzone/index.scss';
import { Modal, Upload, UploadFile } from 'antd';
import { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';
import { motion, useAnimation } from 'framer-motion';
import { defaultTranstion } from '../../../constants/framer';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import FromElemnetWrapper from '../form-element-wrapper';
import { UploadCloud } from 'react-feather';
import { getBase64 } from '../../../utils/get-base64';
import _ from 'lodash';
import config from '../../../api/nuclearMedicineApi/config';
import { FormattedMessage, useIntl } from 'react-intl';
import BasicModal from '../modal';
import { InboxOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';


interface DropzoneProps {
    name: string;
    control: any;
    rules?: any;
    label: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    multiple?: boolean;
    accept?: string;
    refType?: number;
}
const Dropzone: FunctionComponent<DropzoneProps> = ({
    name,
    control,
    rules,
    label,
    disabled,
    multiple,
    accept,
    refType,
}) => {

    const focusController = useAnimation();
    const errorController = useAnimation();
    const [previewVisible, setpreviewVisible] = useState(false);
    const [previewImage, setpreviewImage] = useState('');

    const handleCancel = () => setpreviewVisible(false);
    const handlePreview = async (file: any) => {
        if (!file.url && !file.preview) {
            file.preview = await getBase64(file.originFileObj);
        }
        setpreviewImage(file?.preview ?? file.url);
        setpreviewVisible(true);
    };

    const [file, setFile] = useState<UploadFile[]>()

    const { formatMessage } = useIntl();

    // const onGalleryFileRemove = (_file: UploadFile<any>) => { ... }
    const onGalleryFileRemove = (_file: UploadFile<any>) => {
        const { confirm } = Modal
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            confirm({
                title: formatMessage({ id: 'confirmationDeletePicture' }),
                onOk: () => {
                    resolve(true)
                    // < !----onRemoveFunctionality here---->

                },
                onCancel: () => {
                    reject(true)
                }
            })
        })
    }



    return (
        <>
            <FromElemnetWrapper
                focusController={focusController}
                errorController={errorController}
                label={label}
                required={rules.required?.value}
            >
                <Controller
                    control={control}
                    name={name}
                    rules={rules}
                    render={({
                        field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
                        fieldState: { invalid, error },
                    }) => {
                        if (invalid) {
                            errorController.start({ scale: 80 });
                        } else {
                            errorController.start(
                                { scale: 0 },
                                { ease: defaultTranstion.ease.reverse() },
                            );
                        }
                        return (
                            <div
                                onBlur={() => {
                                    onBlur();
                                    focusController.start({ scale: 0 });
                                }}
                                onFocus={() => {
                                    focusController.start({ scale: 80 });
                                }}
                                className='relative'

                            >
                                <div
                                    className='upload-container'
                                >
                                    <form
                                        className='dropzone needsclick'
                                        id='demo-upload'
                                        action='/upload'
                                    >
                                        <Upload
                                            action={`${config.baseUrl}api/services/app/Attachment/Upload`}
                                            headers={config.headers}
                                            ref={ref}
                                            multiple={multiple}
                                            disabled={disabled}
                                            data={{ RefType: refType }}
                                            listType='picture'
                                            fileList={value}
                                            id={name}
                                            accept={accept}
                                            onPreview={handlePreview}
                                            onChange={(e) => {
                                                onChange(e.fileList),
                                                    setFile(e.fileList)
                                            }
                                            }
                                            onRemove={() => onGalleryFileRemove(file)}
                                        >
                                            <div>
                                                <motion.div
                                                    className='fas fa-angle-double-up'
                                                    whileHover={{
                                                        y: [
                                                            0, -2, 2,
                                                            0,
                                                        ],
                                                        transition: {
                                                            duration: 1.5,
                                                            ease: 'easeInOut',
                                                            yoyo: Infinity,
                                                        },
                                                    }}
                                                >
                                                    <InboxOutlined
                                                        style={{ marginRight: '27rem', marginTop: '5rem', fontSize: '4rem', color: '#179c8b' }}
                                                    />
                                                </motion.div>
                                            </div>
                                        </Upload>
                                        {_.isEmpty(value) && (
                                            <div className='dz-message needsclick'>
                                                <FormattedMessage id='dropfileshere' />
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                        <BasicModal
                                            isOpen={previewVisible}
                                            header={<FormattedMessage id="preview-image" />}
                                            footer={false}
                                            handleCancel={handleCancel}
                                            content={<img
                                                alt='example'
                                                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                                src={previewImage}
                                            />}
                                        />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                {invalid && (
                                    <p className='form-element-error'>
                                        {error?.message}
                                    </p>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </FromElemnetWrapper>
        </>
    );
};

export default Dropzone;
```

Comment: Which line throws this error? You don't need to put all code here. A https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would be better

Comment: in this line // < !----onRemoveFunctionality here---->, i don't know how to write remove function, remove function for arra of images

Comment: Try with `const onGalleryFileRemove = (_file: UploadFile<any>) => { ... }`

Comment: i update my code, but i get error in this line:  onGalleryFileRemove(file) that is: Argument of type 'UploadFile<any>[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UploadFile<any>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typing error tells you that you've provided an invalid callback to the `onRemove` method.

```
<Upload onRemove={() => onGalleryFileRemove(file)} />
```

Your call above is problematic because it uses `file` that is a state on your app, which is an array of files. Moreover your returned promise has an `unknown` return type. But the `onRemove` method only accepts a single file and expects a promise to be resolved with a boolean value. You can do this:

```
const onGalleryFileRemove = (_file: UploadFile<any>) => {
  const { confirm } = Modal

  // Ensure promise returns a boolean
  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
    // Other logic here
  });
};

<Upload onRemove={(file) => onGalleryFileRemove(file)} />
```

...but you can simply bind your `onGalleryFileRemove` directly?

```
<Upload onRemove={onGalleryFileRemove} />
```

That should solve most of your problem as your function type already matches the expected type of `onRemove`.

Comment: i update my code, but i get error in this line: onGalleryFileRemove(file) that is: Argument of type 'UploadFile<any>[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UploadFile<any>'.

Comment: and what is the promise that i must return in this way?

Comment: @HibaYoussef See updated answer: the main issue is you are reading `file` from the wrong place

Comment: How can make the icon and words from right to left?